# Get the currently focused textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two textboxes, and a button. When I press the button, I want to know where my current caret is (either of the two boxes). I need this to know where to insert a certain text. I tried `textbox1.Focused`; `textbox1.enabled` but neither worked. How should I implement this? Thanks

Comment: please see: How do you return the focus to the last used control after clicking a button in a winform app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317/how-do-you-return-the-focus-to-the-last-used-control-after-clicking-a-button-in-a

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep in mind that when you click the button, your textboxes will no longer have focus. You'll want a method of keeping track of what was in focus *before* the button's click event.

Try something like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox focusedTextbox = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            tb.Enter += textBox_Enter;
        }
    }

    void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        focusedTextbox = (TextBox)sender;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (focusedTextbox != null)
        {
            // put something in textbox
            focusedTextbox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to Textbox.GotFocus instead of Textbox.Enter

Comment: As @cod3-monk-3y said.I changed to Gotfocus event.Thank you both of you.It really works :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple way to do this.
Your requirement is simple since you only have two textboxes.

You can assign a class-wide string variable that holds when `textbox1_GotFocus()` is invoked as well as `textbox2_GotFocus()`.
So if that `textbox GotFocus()` is called you assign a value.
Then put a condition for the class-wide string variable in the button that if the class-wide variable has a value of thats kind, that textbox is populated whatever you want to put in the textbox.

It worked for me so I believe it should work on you.