# Change text of selected textbox on button click

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, button, textbox

I've got a problem that involves, on a button click event, changing the text of the currently selected textbox on the form. Is this possible? If so how do I go about doing it?

EDIT: I do not know the name of the textbox, but it will always be the currently selected or 'focused' textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that when you press the button, the Textbox is no longer the focus.
By solution appears [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317/how-do-you-return-the-focus-to-the-last-used-control-after-clicking-a-button-in), You can do this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If lastTextBoxFocused IsNot Nothing Then
        lastTextBoxFocused.Text = "Bla bla, bla!"
    End If
End Sub

Dim lastTextBoxFocused As TextBox
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'find all TextBox's in the Form.
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is TextBox Then
            'attach a lambda expression to each Enter event, to "remember" the last enter
            AddHandler CType(Ctrl, TextBox).Enter, Sub(o, ev) lastTextBoxFocused = o
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```